# CentOS 6.5 + Samba 4.1.6 - Variable Substitution (smb.conf)

Tags: centos, centos6, samba, smb

So, I come to you because I have a little problem when setting up my domain controller based on CentOS 6.5 and Samba 4.1.6.

Everything works well, except for one small detail, which in my case blocking me.

I would like to automatically generate the home directory of the user during the first connection (from Win or Linux), but the problem is that for some unknown reason, the variable substitution does not work in the smb.conf

I tested various alternatives for the user name, for example, but none works.

Here is my smb.conf

```
[global]
        workgroup = ADS
        realm = ADS.LOCAL
        netbios name = BOOS17
        server role = active directory domain controller
        dns forwarder = 172.16.130.7
        server services = rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbind, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate, dns, smb
        dcerpc endpoint servers = epmapper, wkssvc, rpcecho, samr, netlogon, lsarpc, spoolss, drsuapi, dssetup, unixinfo, browser, eventlog6, backupkey, dnsserver, winreg, srvsvc
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

[netlogon]
        path = /usr/local/samba/var/locks/sysvol/ads.local/scripts
        read only = No

[sysvol]
        path = /usr/local/samba/var/locks/sysvol
        read only = No

[home]
        comment = %U %USERNAME% %ACCOUNTNAME% %USERACCOUNT% %u Home Directory
        path = /home/ADS
        read only = No

[Global Share]
        comment = Global %D %DOMAIN% %DOMAINNAME% Share
        path = /home/globalshare
        valid users = User1
        read list = User1
        write list = User1
        read only = No
        guest ok = Yes
```

None of the variables used is replaced.

Here is the result of an example smbclient command:

```
# smbclient -L localhost  -U Administrator -c 'ls'
Enter Administrator's password:
Domain=[ADS] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.6]

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        netlogon        Disk
        sysvol          Disk
        home            Disk      %U %USERNAME% %ACCOUNTNAME% %USERACCOUNT% %u Home Directory
        Global Share    Disk      Global %D %DOMAIN% %DOMAINNAME% Share
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service
Domain=[ADS] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.6]

        Server               Comment
        ---------            -------

        Workgroup            Master
        ---------            -------
```

I dont really know where the problem is.

Someone would have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

Dont using --use-ntvfs in samba-tool option